# highlight fixtures

Tags: libgdx

When you create a fixture in your application, it is not attached to any visual object. Every time I change the coordination of a fixture, I should go hunting for it blindly. Is there a way to tell libgdx to visualize fixture for you for debugging purposes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a debug renderer called `Box2DDebugRenderer`. Just call it with proper params and it will do the job.